# Choosing a set of elements from an array in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an Array  a `(nXn)`. I have another array `b (n X 1).` 
I want to extract those elements from A whose indices are elements of b.  I want the following elements `[a[1, b[1]], a[2,b[2]] ...]`.
Is there a way to perform this without a loop?

EG:
`A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[5,2,8]]`
`B = [2,1,2]`
I need the following Array: `[A[0, B[0]], A[1, B[1]], A[2, B[2]]] = [3, 5, 8]`

Comment: Could you mock up an example of input/output - I'm not quite sure I get what you mean here...

Comment: So you want to obtain the array whose element are `a[i, b[i]]` for all `0 <= i < len(b)`?

Comment: @Bakuriu. Yes, but can I do this without a loop?

Comment: Dup linked question's answer needed `b.ravel()`, because it was `2D`. In your case, you can simply do : `A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),b]`.